# Swift Remove callback from json data

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get some data trough a public API from a website but when they send a response with a callback.
example:

```
execute({"d":{"username":"Avi","status":"Active","regdate":"11/03/2017"}});
```

I'm using SwiftyJSON to parse it but it returns null.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR")
    }
    else {
        print("OK")
        let jd = JSON(data: data!)
        print(jd["d"]["username"])
    }
}
```

I've already tried to cast it to NSString but I couldn't apply any replacement.
Anybody can help?

Comment: Remove `execute(` at the start and remove `);` at the end. Then it will be a valid JSON string. A better option would be to ask the API to not return such a thing (maybe using an URL parameter?) but I guess you don't have much choice if you're asking this.

Comment: Unfortunately the endpoint always return this callback, no url parameter can prevent it.

Comment: Ok. Make a string from the data, remove the extra parts, then either use the string directly or convert it back to data again before deserializing its content.

Answer (score 0):

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("ERROR")
    }
    else {
        print("OK")
        var callback = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)   
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\{(.*)\\}", options:.caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: String(callback).characters.count)
        let results = regex.matches(in: String(callback), options:[], range:range)
        let jsonString = callback.substring(with: results[0].range)
        let jd = JSON(string: jsonString)
        print(jd["d"]["username"])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it thanks to Eric Aya with this:

```
var dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
            dataString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "execute(", with: "")
            dataString = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: ");", with: "")
            let json = dataString?.data(using: .utf8)
            let jsonData = JSON(json!)
```