# Remove substring between parentheses

Tags: swift, swift3

I need a function in Swift 3 which will remove content in a string between parentheses.
E.g for a string like `"THIS IS AN EXAMPLE (TO REMOVE)"`
should return `"THIS IS AN EXAMPLE"`

I'm trying to use `removeSubrange` method but I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you wrote trying `removeSubrange`?

Comment: Similar to my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/42837978/1189470

Comment: title.removeSubrange(title.range(of: "(")!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<strike>Most simple</strike> Shortest solution is regular expression:

```
let string = "This () is a test string (with parentheses)"
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\s?\([\w\s]*\)"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The pattern searches for:

- An optional whitespace character `\s?`.
- An opening parenthesis `\(`.
- Zero or more word or whitespace characters `[\w\s]*`.
- A closing parenthesis `\)`.

Alternative pattern is `#"\s?\([^)]*\)"#` which represents:

- An optional whitespace character `\s?`.
- An opening parenthesis `\(`.
- Zero or more characters *anything but a closing parenthesis* `[^)]*`.
- A closing parenthesis `\)`.

Comment: This doesn't just remove characters in between parentheses; it removes everything after two (or more, I'm sure) pairs of parentheses. For example, the string "This () is a test string (with parentheses)" would turn into "This". Have you run it in a Playground? I just did..

Comment: Cool, looks better

Comment: I'll prefer that answer. Looks like Regex is better than dealing with indexes.

Comment: the `[^)]` pattern will probably work much better in cases when the text between parens contains interpunction (e.g. commas, hyphens etc.).

Comment: This answer does not work well with parentheses inside parentheses. For example: "Ko Phi Phi Don ("ko" (Thai: เกาะ) meaning "island" in the Thai language)" turns into -> "Ko Phi Phi Don meaning "island" in the Thai language)". This should read "Ko Phi Phi Don"

Comment: (Swift 5) `"\\s?\\([\\w\\s]*\\)"` may be a little more readable as `#"\s?\([\w\s]*\)"#`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll only have one pair of parentheses (this only removes the first pair):

```
let s = "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE (TO REMOVE)"
if let leftIdx = s.characters.index(of: "("),
    let rightIdx = s.characters.index(of: ")")
{   
    let sansParens = String(s.characters.prefix(upTo: leftIdx) + s.characters.suffix(from: s.index(after: rightIdx)))
    print(sansParens)
}
```

Comment: Now try with `"THIS IS AN EXAMPLE )TO REMOVE("` or `":) THIS IS AN EXAMPLE (TO REMOVE)"` ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Based on [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913917/4488252) answer

### Details

- swift 4.2
- Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

### Solution

```
extension String {
    private func regExprOfDetectingStringsBetween(str1: String, str2: String) -> String {
        return "(?:\(str1))(.*?)(?:\(str2))"
    }
    
    func replacingOccurrences(from subString1: String, to subString2: String, with replacement: String) -> String {
        let regExpr = regExprOfDetectingStringsBetween(str1: subString1, str2: subString2)
        return replacingOccurrences(of: regExpr, with: replacement, options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let text = "str1 str2 str3 str str1 str4 str5 str1 str1 str6 str1 srt7"
print(text)
print(text.replacingOccurrences(from: "str1", to: "str1", with: "_"))
```

### Results

```
// str1 str2 str3 str str1 str4 str5 str1 str1 str6 str1 srt7
// _ str4 str5 _ str6 str1 srt7
```